# What does Lockheed's StarVision do and what are some comparable products on the market?

Tags: apt

I consult for a client who has Lockheed's StarVision as part of their advanced persistent threats tool set. For various political and business reasons, I have not been able to get a close-up look of the StarVision tool. I tried to "google" StarVision and came up very little, no data sheet or specification of any kind. What are some comparable products on the market I can look at to get a better understanding of StarVision?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about a specific tool that is not readily available to the public.

Comment: Unless we have a previously unknown Lockheed-Martin employee on here willing to break their NDA, it's unlikely you'll get an answer to this question.

Comment: I up voted because it's a good question and I'd like to see the answer. My guess is that it's essentially extra IDS rules for APT.